# Magento setPath for category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I am using PHP to set up my categories in Magento 1.4.2

```
$categories[] = array('id' => '23', 'path' => '16');
$categories[] = array('id' => '24', 'path' => '16/23');
$categories[] = array('id' => '25', 'path' => '16/23/24');

foreach ($categories as $category) {   
    $current_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->load($category['id'])
        ->setPath('1/2/'.$category['path'])
        ->save();
}
```

However something has gone wrong

The categories have been imported like this:

```
root
-23
-16
--24
```

and `25` is nowhere to be seen

Have I got something wrong with my logic or how to use `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` and `->setPath`

Comment: How paths look like in catalog_category_entity table?

Comment: @Eugene Tulika The `catalog_category_entity` table actually looks fine, even the `parent_id` looks fine. The Manage Categories page in the admin panel is still wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this. The path should include the category id too. Thanks to [Eugene Tulika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556196/eugene-tulika) for the pointer in the right direction.

To confirm the $categories array I should have set up was

```
$categories[] = array('id' => '23', 'path' => '16/23');
$categories[] = array('id' => '24', 'path' => '16/23/24');
$categories[] = array('id' => '25', 'path' => '16/23/24/25');
```

Shame I couldn't find any documentation on what to pass to `setPath()` anywhere.